# How to install an app on iPhone from a second machine?

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications

I actually took many hours this morning to find out how to do it, but I want to see alternatives to it.

I got my iPhone in sync with my iTunes at home, my first machine. I could "just" bring the *app* folder/file back home and sync through that. It works just fine.

The question here is on alternatives to that. *Jailbreak* or not, how could we do it on a second machine?

edit: I mean to install an actual file like *application.app* or *application.ipa* [just like they are](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2412838) on the `Mobile Applications` folder or on iPhone's own `/Applications` one.

Comment: Similar question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/sync-itunes-u-on-2-macs-with-an-ipod/2532#2532

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It's quite simple **if** you have *iOS SDK* installed. I've found the solution [in the first place](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/building-devices-iphoneipad#Testing_your_App_on_your_iPhone_or_iPad) I should have looked for, because I actually generated the *app file* using *Corona*. But I suppose this is irrelevant to the question.

**Open Xcode Organizer**, plug in the iDevice and **drag n' drop the app into "applications"**. That's it.

Now, if you don't have iOS SDK, I highly recommend against installing it just for this. It's almost 5GB of downloading. This is why I'd like to know of alternatives.

**edit:** I believe the best way is using the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_iPhone_Configuration_Utility/Introduction/Introduction.html), yet again like that guide from corona. I've confirmed it works just like using the Organizer, but it doesn't need the Xcode. Just [download](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action#downloads) it (this needs a [free login](http://developer.apple.com/programs/register), or find another place on the web with that file, v3.2 is about 10Mb), and drag the *app / ipa* inside your phone. Dealing with licensing the iphone is a [whole nother issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device/4180498#4180498) (don't you love self promoting?).

Comment: The information concerning you developing the application with Corona should have been included in your original question. Development-centric questions like this, while not out of scope, don't get asked much here and you're going to end up with non-development answers. "Using Xcode" is not a reasonable expectation around here.

Comment: @Philip what the heck? I really have no idea what you meant, but this isn't strictly about development at all even if it is the reason that lead me to it. You seem to have looked forward for such a solution, why would you hate it? I brought it here for both document it in a good site and, as a I said, find more alternatives.

Comment: @Cawas: Development scenarios, such as working with an app file that you generated using a third-party SDK, follow a distinctly different workflow than typical users. I think it is safe to say that judging by the types of questions posted here, a vast majority of users do *not* have Apple's development tools installed on their Macs (and does absolutely nothing for Windows-based iTunes users). Yes, doing what you want to do is simple if you have the developer tools installed with an application you created, but you made no mention of that in your original question. [...]

Comment: [...] Stating that information up front puts the question in an entirely different context, and that context is crucial to asking good questions that receive useful answers. The question when held up to the answer you posted do nothing to help either. I don't like downvoting anything, but I feel it is appropriate here.

Comment: @Philip I still can't get what's your point. About the downvoting, go ahead and make the question a CW for what I care. I'm just trying to understand your point. My question does not require SDK, I just gave an answer that do. As I said, I know in the past it was possible to do with JB, and I'm almost positive you can do it with an alternate program without the SDK as well - I just haven't tried and won't for now.

Comment: @Cawas: Okay, one more time... You ultimately were asking the question from a developer's standpoint, which is markedly different than just using iTunes. You were trying to install an application from a second Mac, which, for all intents and purposes, can't be done (at least not without a lot of technical work; see the question linked in the comment to the question). You should have said *up front* that this was an application you built. Developer-related questions and answers, while not technically out of scope, have almost no traction in this forum. Thus, -1. That's it.

Comment: In other words, it's one thing to ling around an application digitally signed by you, it's something else slinging around someone else's you don't have the source code for.

Comment: @Philip I think I see what you mean now. And, as I should be used by now, you did like many others before you and completely missed my point. A very similar question could be done as developer-related. This was not meant to be it. I'm not requesting codes or providing any. There's no compilation or code execution envolved and I brought this from a complete user point of view. Maybe my mistake was trying to be too concise, like in here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4998/why-automatically-adjust-brightness-doesnt-work-after-i-change-the-brightness/5258#5258

Comment: @Cawas: No, you weren't asking for codes, but you were working with applications you built and using tools that clearly aren't typically used by non-developers. Just because you don't ask, provide, or compile code doesn't mean it isn't a developer-related question and answer. Your answer (and thus your question) clearly use developer tools, which gets almost no traction here. I get your point, I just don't agree with it, and I'm not sure how else I can explain this that you'll understand mine as to why the -1 stays. Sorry.

Comment: @Philip still don't care about the -1, your opinion. But if you had got my point you would drop the "no traction here" and "wrong place". My question has no need for developer tools as another answer already proved. If you still think it's the wrong place, flag the question instead of flaming it. It would soon be closed.

Answer (score 4):

For most users, the headache free method is preserving the iTunes folder in its entirety and bringing it over to the other computer. You would then sign into the account you obtain the app with on that computer, and authorize it.

If you're simply without the first computer and want to get the app back, then you would simply re-download from the App Store for free (assuming it hasn't been removed).

Comment: Nice alternative! Very similar to another answer from Philip's link on the question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/sync-itunes-u-on-2-macs-with-an-ipod/2608#2608

Comment: would it make sence to have the iTunes-Folder synchronized through dropbox?

Comment: Nice find, Cawas. As for daefu, syncing via Dropbox is great if you have a library that fits within the size limits of their service. If you're on the same network, then Home sharing might be more appropriate: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3819

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember this question being asked before, but the link eludes me at this moment.

In short, you can't. iPhone syncing is on a per iTunes-installation basis. Plugging the phone into a different machine and trying to sync will result in iTunes asking if you want to wipe the data and re-sync from the new iTunes repository.

Comment: I just said I could, and I know it used to be possible with JB - but I just couldn't do it this time. Sorry I took so long to write my alternative. I'm on it! :P

Comment: @Cawas you will run into the same issue that you asked in your other question.  Anytime there is an update to the app you will need the username and password of the person you got the app from.

Comment: @Ryan not if the app isn't on the apple store! ;)