# Why does iPhone and iPod touch auto-brightness setting work relative to a brightness you set rather than absolute?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, ipod, screen, display

iPhone and iPod Touch aside, I've always considered manual brightness and auto brightness to be mutually exclusive settings.  Intuitively, auto brightness means exactly that - the device figures it out.  Why is the iOS auto brightness setting implemented relative to the manual brightness setting rather than absolute?  In other words, why is manual brightness even an option when auto brightness is selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a one-size-fits-all auto-brightness setting is going to be unpleasant for a large number of users, either because the automatically-selected levels are either too difficult to see, too bright, or eat too much battery.  The automatic setting is based on the threshold you set specifically so that the device can "figure out" ideal settings within a range that you can tolerate.

More to the point, I have a question for you.  Is there a point on the auto-brightness slider that you're comfortable with?  If not, that should be all the proof you need that the slider is necessary!  If there *is* a setting that looks ideal all the time, you've got nothing to complain about - the system works for you.

Comment: Plus, different content will require different brightness levels, and it would be impossible for the os to know how bright a certain app should be. For example, I want my screen to be brighter when playing a game or watching a movie than when reading an email.

Comment: ^ This.  Another excellent point.

Comment: @Kerin - I'm probably being dense but here goes.  :)  Let's say I set the slider at 25% and turn on auto brightness.  At the time I make this setting I do it so the brightness is comfortable at that time.  When I go into a significantly brighter area, not like 12pm on the equator but something more reasonable, the autobrightness setting increases the brightness marginally but not nearly enough to see comfortably.  I think a great brightness configuration would be implemented as follows.  Forget auto-brightness all together.  Then, the user goes into a "dark" situation (cont. -->)

Comment: (cont.), whatever they consider dark to be.  They set the brightness slider so it's comfortable for them in that scenario.  Then for example they go to the normal office daytime situation and set a brightness for there.  And so on, for their environment.  In reality it's probably <= 5 data points.  Once config is done, the sensor picks up the lighting level at a particular scenario (office, dark, etc) and sets the brightness according to their setting for that scenario.

Comment: Eh, your mileage may vary.  For what it's worth I hate, hate, *hate* auto-brightness but the iPhone's is less intolerable than the other implementations I've seen.  Keep in mind that it's hard to *objectively* judge how well-lit a location is, especially when it comes to fluorescent or natural light.  Fluorescent has the aggravating habit of appearing less bright than it is, and expecting the phone to determine what preset brightness level is appropriate is going to be a crapshoot at best.  Is this space dim enough to be preset A, or is the user just holding the device at a different angle?

Comment: I suppose you're point is valid that it could be more intelligent, but I believe it's design goals were simply to tweak a little more battery life out rather than function as an automated system.

Comment: @HandyRandy - I have no idea which of the options - the current method or the method I'm suggesting - would have the least impact on the battery.

Comment: @Kerin - "Less intolerable" - I love it!  I don't think the logic to adjust the brightness to match preset levels would be too difficult.  The light sensor wouldn't have to match exactly; it could do so within some margin of error.  It would be like the your comment about figuring out the right level.  It wouldn't have to be exact just as the current system isn't exact.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the brightness bar is still an option when auto brightness is on is two-fold. First, on the lock screen, when you are putting in your code or just checking time or whatever, the IPhone/IPod Touch uses the actual brightness bar setting for the brightness on lock screen. Auto-brightness only works after you unlock the device (by unlock, i mean the point in time where you can click on apps and such).

Also, the brightness bar sets a quasi-minimum limit, like, if you go into a darkened room like a movie theater, the auto-brightness  will dim the light, up to the level that you have your brightness bar. Kind of like the volume limit for music, except this sets a minimum value instead of a maximum. There are situations where this doesn't apply, which is why i called it a quasi-minimum limit.

For example, if the place you are in is like, literally pitch black (or as close to it as you can achieve, then the difference between your set level and the level the auto-detector wants it to be, is considered extreme, and the auto-detector will override the set level, and put it on the lowest possible brightness.

Hope this helps, seeing as I derived all of this from personal experience with my own usage of the IPhone 3GS and IPhone 4.

Oh, just a note, i mentioned that while on lock screen, the device will use your brightness bar settings, yeah, that only works when it's NOT on the charger. placing the device on charge will automatically put the new lock screen (the one that shows a picture of a battery) on the highest brightness setting.